# Writing a predicate sorted(L)

Tags: prolog

> Write a predicate `sorted(L)` which tests whether a list of integers is sorted, `[n1,n2,...,nk]` where `[n1 < n2 <...< nk]`.

I'm lost. How could I implement this?

Comment: Where n1 what? High to low or low to high?

Comment: I can't understand why someone upvoted this question. It's not even complete.

Comment: sorted(L):-sort(L,L). xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sorted(L) :- hightolow(L) ; lowtohigh(L).

hightolow([H1,H2|T]) :- H1 >= H2, hightolow([H2|T]).
hightolow([_L]).

lowtohigh([H1,H2|T]) :- H1 =< H2, lowtohigh([H2|T]).
lowtohigh([_L]).
```

In action:

```
6 ?- sorted([1,2,3,7,8]).
true 

7 ?- sorted([1,2,3,7,8,2]).
false.

8 ?- sorted([9,6,3,2]).
true .

9 ?- sorted([9,6,3,2,7]).
false.
```

Comment: Based on the information given in a later edit of the question, only lowtohigh is actually needed :)